# Preencher formulário com o ID do cliente

Tags: php, javascript, java, html, ajax

Eu tenho um formulário com ID do cliente, nome do cliente, morada e email.
Como o ID é único queria que quando preenche-se o input do ID, fizesse uma pesquisa na base de dados e completa-se o resto do formulário com os input's que faltam. O problema é que não quero com nenhum botão, queria mesmo depois de preencher "ele" procura-se logo sem actualizar a página nem nada disso.

Answer (score 0):

```
inp.addEventListener("id", function () { 
   //chamada da função que vai preencher os campos
}, false);
```

Comment: Pode fazer só para um input depois eu faço os outros, é que não percebo muito de java.